# Cannot import an Android Code Sample into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I am trying to import an Android Code Sample into Android Studio.
But I get this error.
Please suggest the cause or what's missing.

[image]

Comment: Is your data connection working?

Comment: check you internet connection!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your internet connection and try again, make sure your sdk tools are up to date